# Which hypothesis testing to perform when dataset is combination of paired and unpaired?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I would like to get your help on which hypothesis testing method to choose for the following problem.

Here is an example of my dataset.

In December, We have collected data on vehicle speed of more than 90 KM/Hr. There are ~1200 vehicles. We have implemented some measures that might (or might not) impact the speed. Then collected data again in February. The number of vehicles might vary, some new vehicles might be added, some might be dropped. I would like to know whether there is any impact of the  measures we have taken on speed.

The approach, I have taken is to count daily number of instance when vehicles speeding more than 90 KM/Hr. So for December it's 31 data points and February 20 data points.

I am bit confused whether the dataset should be treated as paired or unpaired. We might record speed from same vehicles or not. Please see the example below.

I would appreciate any suggestion which method to choose. Or may be I should take different approach.

**The initial data for December**

[image]

**Converted to**

[image]

Same was done for February.

Thanks
Moeen

Comment: How did you get the data? Were you collecting from all cars on a given stretch of highway? Or what?

Comment: It's hard to see how you could draw *any* conclusion about your intervention, because it would be confounded with possible changes in traffic pattern due solely to differences in conditions between Feb. and Dec.  You need an experiment with *controls.*

Comment: Hi Peter, We have speedometer and other sensors that transmit telemetry data. We have a fleet of ~1200 vehicles.

Comment: Hi Whuber, You are right. Actually, it's not only speed, I can not disclose the exact sensor data here. Lets say the parameter (fourth column in the example initial dataset after speed) doesn't depend on traffic situation or other external effects.

Comment: Some links which might help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25941/t-test-for-partially-paired-and-partially-unpaired-data, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/620983/robustness-of-mann-whitney-u-test-for-partially-paired-data, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/371590/what-hypothesis-test-to-use-for-partially-paired-non-normal-data, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/427010/mix-of-paired-and-independent-data-analysis

Comment: Hi Kjetil, Thanks